# Temparture and Fan Monitoring

Tags: fan, temperature, conky

Hello Ubuntu friends 
From Hardinfo : 
Processor       : AMD A10-6800K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Motherboard     : Asus a88x bios 1202
Memory          : 15551MB (8779MB used)
Machine Type    : Desktop
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Kernel          : Linux 5.15.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Version         : #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31

From sensors
radeon-pci-0008      Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:               +1.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
k10temp-pci-00c3     Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:               +2.2°C  (high = +70.0°C) (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +69.0°C)

Im using lm-sensors and Psensor-GUI and Conky
Both Temp1 reading are below 7°C usually hovering around 1°C 
I know that in the bios the reading is around 45°C 
What is the mistery trick to get the correct temperature reading ? 
In Psensor I'm getting correct temp reading for the SSD and HDD

There are 3 fans on the board, the fanspeeds are missing, any tricks on making those visible ?

Comment: Did you run `sensors-detect` first?

Comment: Yes I did run sensors-detect first,

Comment: When you run it, does it detect anything in the SuperIO section?  Is it able to identify what the chip is?  You might see something like `Found unknown chip with ID 0x8603`

Answer (score 0):

I would use vitals:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/

It doesn't need lm-sensors to work. Requires (sudo) apt install chrome-gnome-shell. Works with all browsers though snap version of Firefox doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Vitals is interesting  the way it sits in your statusbar, 
But it doesn't solve the issue with wrong temperature output and the lack of fan info

Comment: Well yeah, some chip-sets are not that co-operative with lm-sensors due lack of proper driver. My old PC (Asus Asus F1A75-M PRO) had this kind of chip-set and Linux is unable to provide information of some sensors. Typically these sensors chip support are average calculating analog to digital ones. ref. https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/134. Hardinfo is bound to same mods for kernel so information is not available for it either.